# Darktable : Compare before and after quickly

Tags: workflow, darktable, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to quickly compare before and after in Darktable?

I know how it can be done using the snapshot panel, but is there a way to do it faster?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Undo and Redo keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y on Windows and Linux, CMD-Z and CMD-shift-Z on Apple) operate in Darktable - at least, they do running in Ubuntu : I haven't checked the other OSs. More Darktable shortcuts [here](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/shortcuts.html).

If you're looking for a way to view the image with and without a specific module effect, each module has a "power switch" at its top left corner, so each module - or several - can be switched on or off.

More details on modules (including activating and deactivating them) [here](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/interacting.html).

If you're looking to compare before and after side by side as two images, it looks like that isn't yet in the main distributions of Darktable, though there's a discussion about that [here](https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/8673).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I am looking for a solution where I can compare two stages without the splitscreen method that the snapshots comparison offer. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Undo/redo will do it for a before/after view of the same picture, as will switching on and off modules. No splitscreen involved. If what you're looking for is a side by side comparison of the two views (ie. showing both) it looks like there may be a test version that does that, but it's not (yet?) in the main distribution. I'll edit to add a link.